# "Come, sit" or "Come sit"?

Tags: verbs, commas

I often see both appearances "**Come, sit...**" and "**Come sit...**", which is correct?

P.s. what if there are three consecutive verbs?

- Come, sit, tell me your story.
- Come sit, tell me your story.

Comment: Typographic conventions attempting to represent speech are not fixed.  You could just as easily punctuate that as *Come, sit. Tell me your story*.  or *Come, sit, and tell me...*  **Come**, like **go**, can be complemented by bare infinitive(s).

Comment: Come, sit, and tell me your story. This is more appropriate(very likely), coz come sit, tell me your story might be misinterpreted(particularly come sit(it's like a newly formed phrasal verb), also, when you pronounce the verbs: come(1st stress),sit(2nd stress)......story(3rd stress).. people will undertand you more clearly.

Comment: Commas in written language only mirror the pauses in spoken language.  Can you say "Come sit" with no pause?  Yes.  Can you put a pause in there, "Come, sit."  Yes.   Which is more natural?  It depends on the context of the rest of the sentence, and who is doing the talking.

Comment: Come, sit. Tell me your story. versus: Come sit here [and tell me your story]. Come sit. [one sentence,  yes] but not: Come sit, tell me your story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not the only alternatives. You could also have three complete imperative sentences.

> Come. Sit. Tell me your story.

However, there is a pattern "come" or "go" followed by a bare infinitive.

> Come play tennis.
>
> Let's go eat.

This pattern is mostly used in speech. The expression "come play" acts like a single verb. It forms a single intonation phrase when spoken; there is no pause between the words "come" and "play". When used like this it would not be separated by a comma.

The last part "tell me your story" is a complete sentence. So a full-stop would not be out of place. My prefered punctuation for how I would speak this phrase would be:

> Come sit. Tell me your story.

The comma separated version is completely understandable. It is in no way ambiguous. I doubt anyone would care very much if you put commas between each verb.

Answer (score 1):

> P.s. what if there are three consecutive verbs?
>
> Come, sit, tell me your story. Come sit, tell me your story.

You can have more than three. There are many possible formulations depending on pauses and emphasis.

Come, sit, have a glass of wine, tell me your story.

Come and sit. Have a glass of wine and tell me your story.

Come sit and have a glass of wine. Tell me your story.

etc.